# multi-part identifier can't be bound error when adding "Order By" clause in Access 2010

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2010

I'm building a form with 2 subforms in Access 2010 ADP to SQL Server 2008. I've got the fields and everything showing like I want them to and hooking into the controls okay. However, when I try to sort the Record Source, I get the "multipart identifier can't be bound" error. If I run the SQL in the Query builder in access, it returns records fine. It's just when the form loads that it throws the error. If I remove the Order By out of the SQL, the form loads just fine.

Record Source of subform:

```
SELECT      tblTaskTracker.EmployeeID, tblTaskTracker.ProjectID, tblTaskTracker.ReleaseID, tblTaskTracker.TaskStatusID, tblTaskTracker.TaskPriorityID, 
                        tblTaskTracker.DueDate, tblTaskTracker.Notes, tblTaskTracker.CompDate, tblTaskTracker.QCByID, tblTaskTracker.QCDate, tblProject.ProjectName, 
                        tblTaskCode.TaskCodeAbbr
FROM          tblTaskTracker INNER JOIN
                        tblProject ON tblTaskTracker.ProjectID = tblProject.ProjectID INNER JOIN
                        tblTaskCode ON tblTaskTracker.TaskCodeID = tblTaskCode.TaskCodeID INNER JOIN
                        tblTaskStatus ON tblTaskTracker.TaskStatusID = tblTaskStatus.TaskStatusID
WHERE      (tblTaskStatus.TaskStatusType = 'A')
```

If I add

```
ORDER BY tblTaskTracker.TaskPriorityID
```

at the end, I can click Run and I get the expected results back. However, when I close out of the query builder and try to load the form, I get the multi-part identifier "tblTaskTracker.TaskPriorityID" could not be bound. I click OK on that message and that subform doesn't load.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend becoming familiar with writing your own queries instead of the query builder. Then you can start using aliases and your queries will be much simpler to maintain.

```
SELECT tt.EmployeeID
    , tt.ProjectID
    , tt.ReleaseID
    , tt.TaskStatusID
    , tt.TaskPriorityID
    , tt.DueDate
    , tt.Notes
    , tt.CompDate
    , tt.QCByID
    , tt.QCDate
    , p.ProjectName
    , tc.TaskCodeAbbr
FROM tblTaskTracker tt
INNER JOIN tblProject p ON tt.ProjectID = p.ProjectID 
INNER JOIN tblTaskCode tc ON tt.TaskCodeID = tc.TaskCodeID 
INNER JOIN tblTaskStatus ts ON tt.TaskStatusID = ts.TaskStatusID
WHERE ts.TaskStatusType = 'A'
ORDER BY tt.TaskPriorityID
```

For the issue at hand, look at your tables and make sure that column in the order by is spelled correctly and that it exists in that table.

Comment: I know that his is not a typo issue and that it exists in the table. This is part of why I used the query builder. In the row for the TaskPriorityID, I simply clicked the Sort Type as Ascending, and Set the Sort Order to 1. The resulting 'ORDER BY tblTaskTracker.TaskPriorityID' is what was generated as a result. I've been over it with a fine toothed comb and even squinted really hard at the monitor. No typos.

Comment: Well unless you can post some table definitions the best we can do is guess. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE tblTaskTracker(
   TaskID         INT  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)
  ,EmployeeID     INT  NOT NULL
  ,ProjectID      INT  NOT NULL
  ,ReleaseID      INT  NOT NULL
  ,TaskCodeID     INT  NOT NULL
  ,TaskStatusID   INT  NOT NULL
  ,TaskPriorityID INT  NOT NULL
  ,DueDate        DATETIME  NOT NULL
  ,Notes          NVARCHAR()
  ,CompDate       DATETIME 
  ,QCByID         INT 
  ,QCDate         DATETIME 
);
INSERT INTO tblTaskTracker(TaskID,EmployeeID,ProjectID,ReleaseID,TaskCodeID,TaskStatusID,TaskPriorityID,DueDate,Notes,CompDate,QCByID,QCDate) VALUES
 (1,206,14331,1,1,1,3,'2016-05-04 00:00:00.000',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)
,(2,206,14331,1,2,2,3,'2016-05-04 00:00:00.000',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
```

What's making me scratch my head at what's going on is that whether I run the original SQL with the ORDER BY clause in SSMS or in Access, the results come back with the expected data. It's only on form load that the error comes up. For what it's worth, the main form has no OnLoad event. Both subforms have the following VBA to set the column width of the subform Datasheet.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.txtProjectID.ColumnWidth = 1440 * 0.75
    Me.txtProjectName.ColumnWidth = 1440 * 2
    Me.txtReleaseNum.ColumnWidth = 1440 * 0.75
    Me.txtTaskCode.ColumnWidth = 1440 * 0.75
    Me.cboStatus.ColumnWidth = 1440 * 1
    Me.cboPriority.ColumnWidth = 1440 * 1
    Me.txtDueDate.ColumnWidth = 1440 * 1
    Me.txtNotes.ColumnWidth = 1440 * 2
    Me.txtCompDate.ColumnWidth = 1440 * 1
    Me.cboQCEmp.ColumnWidth = 1440 * 1.5
    Me.txtQCDate.ColumnWidth = 1440 * 1
End Sub
```